# How to pass data to vue router router-view?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Im using Vue Router. In my code I used to have:

```
<div v-bind:is="page.component_name" v-bind:page="page"></div>
```

Which worked, and the `page` data was passed to the component. But how do I do the same with a router-view? This doesn't seem to work:

```
<router-view v-bind:page="page"></router-view>
```

js:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    ...,
    router : new VueRouter({
        routes : [
            { path: '/foo', component: { template: '<div>foo</div>', created:function(){alert(1);} } },
            //{ path: '/bar', component: { template: '<div>bar</div>', created:function(){alert(2);} } },
            { path: '/bar', component: Vue.component("ti-page-report") }
        ]
    }),
     ...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vue-router` has a dedicated page in docs on how to pass props to `router-view`.

[Passing Props to Route Components](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html)

Example snippet from docs:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/user/:id', component: User, props: true },

     // for routes with named views, you have to define the `props` option for each named view:
    {
      path: '/user/:id',
      components: { default: User, sidebar: Sidebar },
      props: { default: true, sidebar: false }
    }
  ]
})
```

If you are looking for simplified usage, `props` can still be passed the same way they are passed to any component. But component that is used for rendering the route (the one that is specified in route definition) should expect to receive the props.

Here is simple usage example of passing `props` to `router-view`:

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: How would I set it up, so I can access `page.icon` for example in the component?

Comment: The example code is confusing as it doesn't show how to access the prop values from the component.

Comment: I've added simplified usage example to the answer. Please, check the way `title` prop is passed to `<router-view>`. Does this help your issue?

Comment: In my case, the :title="...", the ... is a function which gets the right data based on a click event that needs to happen first, however the router "to" happens before and then I get a bunch of console errors about undefined values.

Comment: nvm i solved it with this https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/800

Comment: There are different ways to fetch data on router navigation and solution may be different on your app's architecture. Here is an example of using [In-component navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards): [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y05q645jrz)

Answer (score 1):

I personally decided to use [provide/inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html) feature: preserving reactivity with minimal overhead.

Comment: Please add some further information on how you would solve it using the technique you mention.

Answer (score 0):

The component ("ti-page-report") that needs to access the props being sent just needs to add it:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Now you can access page: {{ page }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  name: "TiPageReport",
  props: ['page'], // can now be accessed with this.page
  ...
};
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html for how to use props properly.